# What does the ** operator mean in C?

Tags: c

Does `**` have any special meaning in C?

Like this:

```
static intparse_one (int argc, char **argv)
{
    cmd_line       *slot;
    int             value;
    Flag_name       flag_name;
    int         i;

printf("argv %s\n",argv);
printf("argv[0] %c\n",**argv);
```

If so, does the line

```
**argv
```

make sense?  A program I am trying to get to run is choking on it. If I try to print it I get a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

The first printf prints the string fine. The second printf fails.

Here is what I am getting for the output (The first line is correct):

```
argv -aps_instance1001-aps_ato0-aps_ipc_debug3

Segementation Fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "choking" ? That comparison is valid; it essentially looks to see if the first character of the first argument is a hyphen. (That's probably not what you mean, since the first argument is generally the binary's name, not a getopt-style flag)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> "Does ** have any special meaning in C?"

No, it is just two [dereferences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator).

```
char **argv
```

means: `argv` dereferenced two times is a `char`. In other words `argv` is a pointer to a pointer to `char`.

---

The same for:

> "If so, does the line:  `**argv`        make sense?"

The declaration says that `**argv` is a `char`. At runtime `argv` will be dereferenced two times; the value is the `char` that `argv`, the pointer to a pointer to `char`, is pointing to.

Answer (score 2):

`**` is just two `*`.

As far as the segfault goes, look at your line `printf("argv %s\n",argv);`.  The `printf` expects a `char *`, not `char **`, and so it's looking at an array of pointers rather than an array of characters.  `printf` is trying to print everything at `argv` as a string of characters until it encounters a zero, and probably goes out of bounds before it finds one.

`argv` is a `char **`, which is a pointer to a pointer, or in this case an array of pointers.  Don't print it directly, because it has no external meaning.  (You can print the pointer value if you want to see it, of course.)

`*argv` or `argv[0]` is a `char *`, which is a pointer to `char`, which in this case is the first string in `argv`.

`**argv` is a `char`, which in this case is the first character of the first string in `argv`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> char **argv

is the same thing as

> char* argv[]

Answer (score 1):

No.

Every `*` introduces a level of indirection. In this context, it means that `argv` is a pointer to a pointer. Which it is not, really, as technically you can see it a an array of pointers - it can be declared as `char * argv[]`.

Obviously, by "no", I mean that `**` is not special in itself. Or it is special, but neither more nor less than `*` or `***`.

Answer (score 1):

`char **argv` is same as `char *argv[]`.

Here `argv` is the argument vector.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that a pointer to a pointer? I think the ** in front of the argv parameter has the same effect as `ref` in C#, in case you know C#.

Answer (score 0):

While the string "`**`" does have a well defined meaning, I think the answer to the questions is "**" is not one operator, but two "`*`" in a row.

This is in contrast to [Fortran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran) where "`**`" is a single token and functions as the exponentiation operator.

So the meaning is [well covered by Martin Beckett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404216/help-with-operator-in-c/2404230#2404230), but it really isn't "an operator".